# Setting only of background or text color back to default

Tags: terminal, colors

Is it possible to only reset the background color or text color back to default (not both!)

Example:

```
echo -e "\033[32;41mFoo bar\033[30m baz" # Doesn't reset background color
echo -e "\033[32;41mFoo bar\033[0m baz" # Resets the background color and text color
```

Is there anyway to do this?

I know I can assign the background color in the second statement, but the color will be unknown. (`echo -e "\033[32;41mFoo bar\033[0m baz"`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The colors `39` and `49` means the default color, for the foreground and the background respectively. `\e[0m` is equivalent to `\e[22;24;25;27;28;39;49m` (not bold, not underlined, not blinking, not inverse, not hidden, default foreground, default background).

You can find the terminal control sequences in the [xterm documentation](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#ctlseqs_ms) (most terminals follow xterm's lead nowadays).